# Parceling a Violin from Japan to Bangladesh

Tags: taxes, gift-tax, japan, bangladesh

I'm a student and saved some money with part time jobs for a violin. I want a friend of mine to parcel a violin purchased in Japan to Bangladesh. Will he need to pay taxes to send me that violin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 10% VAT in Japan, ask your friend to get the shop to arrange a tax rebates for foreign purchase. Then you need to pay the customs duty when import into Bangladesh, it can be arranged by the shipping company.

However, after looking into the [Bangladesh import tax table](http://www.bangladeshcustoms.gov.bd/trade_info/duty_calculator), Violin is under the following code

- 9202.10.00   String Musical Instruments Played With A Bow 60.31%
- brief Duty breakdown : Custom duty 25%, VAT 15%, Advance Income Tax 5%, Regulatory Duty 3% , advance trade VAT 5%

I think you should talk to the local musician on how they get their instruments than doing it yourself.  Since this doesn't look like a viable idea for a student.

p/s: Looking at the tax schedule, I bet custom works is a "lucrative job" in Bangladesh.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborative answer in a disciplined manner. I will look for local musicians about this.